# Select rows without missing values in R

Tags: r

I am a new user to R and for loop.  I am trying to take sampling from data and check to see if there is a colinear column.  I want to record in that iteration that the colinear column exists and record it in the vector (baditr).  Also, I would like to print a line indicating that "colinearity is at iteration i".  Then I would like the code to jump to the second iteration and continue running. For each iteration, I would like the code to save the sum of the columns in the corresponding row of the matrix.

My problem is that I am getting an NA for the bad iterations.  My intent is for bad iterations to not be included in my matrix at all.   Here is my code:

```
a0=rep(1,40)
a=rep(0:1,20)
b=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))
c0=c(rep(0,12),rep(1,28))
c1=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,35))
c2=c(rep(1,8),rep(0,32))
c3=c(rep(1,23),rep(0,17))
da=matrix(cbind(a0,a,b,c0,c1,c2,c3),nrow=40,ncol=7)
sing <- function(nrw){
  sm <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrw,ncol=ncol(da))
  baditr <- NULL
  for(i in 1:nrw){
    ind <- sample(1:nrow(da), nrow(da),replace =TRUE)
    smdat <- da[ind,]
    evals <- eigen(crossprod(smdat))$values
    if(any(abs(evals) < 1e-7)){
      baditr <- c(baditr,i)
      cat("singularity occurs at", paste(i),"\n")
      next
    }
  sm[i,] <- apply(smdat,2,sum)
  }
  return(sm)
}
sing(20)
```

I will get the following output:

```
singularity occurs at 9 
singularity occurs at 13 
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]   40   23   22   25    5    8   26
 [2,]   40   20   18   30    4    7   22
 [3,]   40   19   24   28    6    7   25
 [4,]   40   19   22   30    6    9   26
 [5,]   40   12   26   26    8   13   30
 [6,]   40   17   16   27    7   10   19
 [7,]   40   20   17   33    3    5   19
 [8,]   40   22   19   28    4    9   23
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   40   21   24   28    3    6   27
[11,]   40   21   16   31    2    4   22
[12,]   40   21   21   26    3    6   23
[13,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[14,]   40   18   16   29    2    7   22
[15,]   40   24   18   30    6    9   21
[16,]   40   23   18   29    4    8   21
[17,]   40   17   25   25    3    8   29
[18,]   40   22   28   23    9   14   30
[19,]   40   25   23   25    7   11   30
[20,]   40   20   23   27    7   10   26
```

I would like my matrix to look like this:

```
singularity occurs at 9 
singularity occurs at 13 
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]   40   23   22   25    5    8   26
 [2,]   40   20   18   30    4    7   22
 [3,]   40   19   24   28    6    7   25
 [4,]   40   19   22   30    6    9   26
 [5,]   40   12   26   26    8   13   30
 [6,]   40   17   16   27    7   10   19
 [7,]   40   20   17   33    3    5   19
 [8,]   40   22   19   28    4    9   23
[10,]   40   21   24   28    3    6   27
[11,]   40   21   16   31    2    4   22
[12,]   40   21   21   26    3    6   23
[14,]   40   18   16   29    2    7   22
[15,]   40   24   18   30    6    9   21
[16,]   40   23   18   29    4    8   21
[17,]   40   17   25   25    3    8   29
[18,]   40   22   28   23    9   14   30
[19,]   40   25   23   25    7   11   30
[20,]   40   20   23   27    7   10   26
```

As a fail safe, I would also appreciate any information you may have on saving a certain number of iterations to a file (for example, 50 iterations), which I can override once the next number of iterations is produced.  Meaning, I save the first 50 iterations to a file and then once the second round of 50 iterations is produced, they override the first round and as a result, my file now has 100 iterations.

Sorry for the long post.  But thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking at the mechanics of the function, if you want to return `sm` without the `NA` values, then `return(na.omit(sm))` will do the trick

Comment: @mnel thank you I forgot about this command. because my main problem is with the next command on my original code i am check if there is a collinearity in the data to fit or not a model, "so the condition I am impose is if there is collinearity let me know at what iteration and don't fit the model then start the next iteration". also the problem with saving to file at certain number of iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you return `sm`, you can filter out the rows with `NA` values by using `complete.cases()`. It would look something like `sm[complete.cases(sm),]`. The function returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE values, which forces R to not return those values with FALSE.

Also, it doesn't look like you are doing anything with `baditers` after defining it.I can comment out all lines referring to `baditers` and your function seems to work just fine...maybe it's a legacy from an older iteration of your code?

## Update

Here's your updated function using `complete.cases()`. Note I also commented out everything related to `baditr` to illustrate that it's not doing anything currently in your code.

```
sing <- function(nrw){
  sm <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrw,ncol=ncol(da))
  #baditr <- NULL
  for(i in 1:nrw){
    ind <- sample(1:nrow(da), nrow(da),replace =TRUE)
    smdat <- da[ind,]
    evals <- eigen(crossprod(smdat))$values
    if(any(abs(evals) < 1e-7)){
      #baditr <- c(baditr,i)
      cat("singularity occurs at", paste(i),"\n")
      next
    }
    sm[i,] <- apply(smdat,2,sum)
  }
  return(sm[complete.cases(sm),])
}
```

Now let's run the function, I'm wrapping `dim()` around the function call which will tell us the #rows and #columns of the resulting object:

```
> dim(sing(20))
singularity occurs at 6 
[1] 19  7
```

So one singularity and a matrix of 19 rows and 7 columns, am I missing something?

As to your other question about writing things out, are you aware of the `append` parameter to `write.table()` and friends? The help page tells us that `If TRUE, the output is appended to the file. If FALSE, any existing file of the name is destroyed.`

## Update 2

Here's an example using `append = TRUE` in `write.table()`

```
#Matrix 1 definition and write to file
x <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
write.table(x, "out.txt", sep = "\t", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
#Matrix 2 definition and write to same file with append = TRUE
x2 <- matrix(10:18, ncol = 3)
write.table(x2, "out.txt", sep = "\t", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
#read consolidated data back in to check if it's right
x3 <- read.table("out.txt", header = TRUE)
```

Results in

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
4 10 13 16
5 11 14 17
6 12 15 18
```

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work any other suggestions. what about the saving into file at certain number of iteration

Comment: @frespider - added what your modified function could look like, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please explain more about write.table and append